# Xcode progress bar using swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I’m trying to add a progress bar at the top of my app for each screen a green bar appears so you can map your progress as you move through the app

How can I do this in Xcode using swift ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to **SO**! Please provide a [mcve]. Feel free to look around the [help], and make sure to take the [tour]. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by adding that to the main window like this , by this it will be shown inside any VC , you can tag it to access inside other VC

```
let v = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 100))

v.tag = 22  

v.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

let w = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

w.window?.addSubview(v)
```